# How to draw an outline around a column?

Tags: ios, objective-c, border

I would like to draw an outline around a column. here is how my app actually looks like: https://gyazo.com/80dffe6a153e82565a610222a43e0c11

So the white column represent the day on where we are actually. But I don't really want to do that.

Actually I'm doing this:

```
if(column == _intOfTheDay){ //intOfTheDay represent the day one where we are actually
    cell.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor]colorWithAlphaComponent:0.95];        
}
```

I've tried something like this to get closer of the result that I want:

```
if(column == _intOfTheDay){
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 5.0f;
    cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;        
}
```

But the problem here (without all the bugs due to the `UICollectionView`) is that it draw a rectangle around each cell. And what I would like is to draw only one rectangle but around all the column.
How could I process?

Every help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Subclass the collection view cell and over-write your draw code there ....

Comment: Do you want to set border to column means to number of cell of particular column and not to cell ? rectangular box type or cup board type shape right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to subclass the UICollectionViewCell then use this :

```
float borderWidth = 5.0;
CALayer *leftBorder = [CALayer new];
leftBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, borderWidth, cell.frame.size.height);
leftBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
[cell.layer addSublayer:leftBorder];

CALayer *rightBorder = [CALayer new];
rightBorder.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width - borderWidth, 0.0, borderWidth, cell.frame.size.height);
rightBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
[cell.layer addSublayer:rightBorder];
```

Comment: You're the real MVP haha thanks a lot, Now I've got what I want, I'll work on the collection view's issues

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, set three border to first cell of column- left,right and top and for last cell of column left,right and bottom and for all middle cell left and right. you can use `CALayer` to set one side border like below example,

```
 CALayer *TopBorder = [CALayer layer];
TopBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.myImageView.frame.size.width, 3.0f);
TopBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
[cell.layer addSublayer:TopBorder];
```